# Select columns dynamically from a while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to dynamically select my columns from a table (dbo.Ordinal) which lists every column and it's position. These column headings correspond to the table Y2.

```
DECLARE 
@ord int = 1,
@colname varchar(max),
@div varchar(max) = '',
@sql varchar (max)


WHILE @ord < 3 BEGIN
    SET @ord = @ord + 1

    Set @colname = '(SELECT BR FROM dbo.[Ordinal] WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION=' +CAST(@ord AS Varchar(10))+')'  

    SET @div = @div + ',' +(@colname)
END


Set @sql = '(SELECT Simulation' + @div + ' FROM dbo.[Y2 HR]) ORDER BY Simulation'


EXECUTE (@sql)
```

This code currently fills the resulting table with the column title I am trying to select. Ideally i'd like to see @div producing a text string opf the desired columns that can then be used in @sql,

Currently if I print @sql, the output is :

```
(SELECT Simulation,(SELECT BR FROM dbo.[Ordinal] WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION=2),(SELECT BR FROM dbo.[Ordinal] WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION=3) FROM dbo.[Y2 HR]) ORDER BY Simulation.
```

Any way to achieve this or suggestions for a different approach are welcome

Thanks

Comment: sql server? oracle ? mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it much simpler:

```
DECLARE 
@ord int = 1,
@colname varchar(max),
@div varchar(max) = '',
@sql varchar (max)


WHILE @ord < 3 BEGIN
    SET @ord = @ord + 1

    SELECT @colname = BR FROM dbo.[Ordinal] WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION= @ord

    SET @div = @div + ',' +(@colname)
END


Set @sql = '(SELECT Simulation' + @div + ' FROM dbo.[Y2 HR]) ORDER BY Simulation'


EXECUTE (@sql)
```